# how to run function to selection which is dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending some HTML elements to the page dynamically. There can be multiple items added and can be added a different times...so it is hard to use a "bind".

I decided to use an inline function---but this does not work on Firefox...works on all other browsers. Notice the onClick for the options. Also, I have tried onblur, onchange, and on select. None of these work with Firefox.

My goal is to have these functions run when the option is selected. I guess I am just missing something.

```
$("#billTasks").find('tr')
  .append('<td><fieldset><select>
           <option class="fixedRate" onClick="fixedOption(this)" id="billFixedSelect" value="1">Fixed Rate</option>
           <option class="hourly"  onClick="hourlyOption(this)" id="billHourlySelect" value="2"></option>
           </select>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Rate" class="fieldWidth100 rate currency" style="margin-right:10px;"/>
           <select class="schedule">
           <?php while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)){
                echo "<option value=\'{$row['schedule']}\'>{$row['schedule']}</option>\\n";}?>
           </select></fieldset></td>');
```

This is the code in question (in the append string)

```
<select>
    <option class="fixedRate" onClick="fixedOption(this)" id="billFixedSelect" value="1">Fixed Rate</option>
    <option class="hourly"  onClick="hourlyOption(this)" id="billHourlySelect" value="2"></option></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why Inline You try some thing like this.

```
$("#billTasks").find('select').live("change", function() {
  var SelectedValue = $(this).val();
  if (SelectedValue == '1') {
  //your task                      
  }
  if (SelectedValue == '2') {
  //Your Task                     
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate event handler for that:

```
$('#billTasks ').on('change', 'select', function() {
  // your code
  hourlyOption(this); // here this points to select itself
});
```

Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: if you notice each option carries a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a class for this. What you could do is something like this:

```
function Option(html, events) {
    var o = $(html);
    for(var k in events) {
        o.bind(k, events[k]);
    }
    return o;
}
```

Use this something like this:

```
var o = new Option('<option>blah</option>', { click: function() { } ... });
```

and `o` is just a new jquery object. So you can use it anyway.